# Tracking Referer with JS and PHP : Problems with IE

Tags: php, javascript

I want to build a tracker application where the end user gets a JS code which he puts on his website. I want to track data related to that website like http referer.

What I am currently doing is to feed the client jQuery and a code snippet. The JS checks document.referer and sends that back to my php script via jQuery ajax GET call.

It's working fine in FF and others. I am having issues in IE only.

Can somebody please provide me a solution that works with IE.

Thanks

Comment: can you pleas post the code you are using? also a description of why its not working or what happens in IE would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue with IE since the dawn of time

Do not rely on referer for anything

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178066

[Internet Explorer http referer issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402065/internet-explorer-http-referer-issue)