# Code redirect in javascript from a 302

Tags: javascript

This code works in Google Chrome but not in IE and Firefox.
The site "somesite.org" send me 302 (redirect).
I want to redirect when it comes from a specific site (somesite.org) to a specific file in my site.

Code:

```
var url = document.referrer; 

if (url.includes("somesite.org")) { 
    window.location.href = "http://forthisfile.com/this.html"
}
```

Comment: See: IE did not set document.referrer StackOverFlow: [Equivalent document.referrer others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681156/ie-did-not-set-document-referrer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not support any form of includes, see [MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility).

that said, the alternative is to check the hash:

```
if(window.location.hash.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

so in your case:

```
  if(window.location.hash.indexOf("somesite.org") > -1 ){

      window.location = "http://forthisfile.com/this.html" ;
    }
```

Comment: Works fine in Chrome, same as before in IE and Firefox. I saw that the referer in IE and Firefox comes in blank, different from chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var url = document.referrer;

    if(url.indexOf("somesite.org") > -1 ){

      window.location = "http://forthisfile.com/this.html" ;
    }
```

Comment: Works only in Chrome too. Nothing in IE, firefox and edge.

Comment: @BRS , I tried in Firefox . It is working as expected. Any specific errors you saw?

Comment: If a site has a redirect, I can not send it to a specific page, just with Google Chrome.
If it's a link, all browsers works fine with both codes.
Without specific error.

Comment: Sorry in IE I have this error:  Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

Comment: @BRS, in that case you might wanna try 'indexOf' property. Updated answer for the same.

Comment: What is the version of IE browser?

Comment: Works fine in Chrome, same as before in IE and Firefox. I saw that the referer in IE and Firefox comes in blank, different from chrome.

Comment: @BRS , for this case specific to IE, you can check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1890744/4749442

Comment: @AnshulBansal all browsers in last stable version released. I will try check answer stackoverflow.com/a/1890744/4749442.