# request.getHeader("referer") is not working Internet Explorer

Tags: java, jsp, http, internet-explorer, servlets

How to get previous URL in jsp page. I used the code

String previousURL = request.getHeader("referer");

We are landing in this page with ajax call to this page, I need to authenticate the user and take them back to the page from where they have come before login.

"request.getHeader" working fine in all other browsers like Chrome,Firefox,Edge. But in Internet explorer its returning null value. Please guide me in this issue.

I am not getting how to solve this issue, should I use session to store the previous url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer http referer issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402065/internet-explorer-http-referer-issue)

Comment: I tried the above answers,and non of them are working. Moreover I am using JSP not in HTML. I have to use scriplet to get the value of url. I can get the value easily in javascript.